# Getting bash getopts to do something

Tags: bash

I am attempting to figure out how to use bash getopts to process command lines. I have the following code:

```
    while getopts "e:n:t:s:h" opt
        do

            echo $opt
        done
```

I invoke it with a bash command line like this:

. ./testopts.sh -e MyE -s sanctity

and nothing gets printed.

Please help

Comment: How about some google? http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial

Answer (score 2):

`$opt` will only print switches `e` or `s` for you but to print passed argument you need to echo `$OPTARG` as well.

Like this script:

```
while getopts "e:n:t:s:h" opt
do
   echo $opt $OPTARG
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an template what i'm using for argument processing.

It is far from optimal (for example uses too much sed, instead of builtin bash regexes and so on) but you can use it for the start:

```
#!/bin/bash

#define your options here
OPT_STR=":hi:o:c"

#common functions
err() { 1>&2 echo "$0: Error: $@"; return 1; }
required_arg() { err "Option -$1 need argument"; }
checkarg() { [[ "$1" =~ ${optre:--} ]] && { required_arg "$2"; return 1; } || { echo "$1" ; return 0; } }
phelp() { err "Usage: $0" "$(sed 's/^://;s/\([a-zA-Z0-9]\)/ -&/g;s/:/ [arg] /g;s/  */ /g' <<< "$OPT_STR")"; return 1; }

do_work() {
    echo "Here should go your script for processing $1"
}

## MAIN
declare -A OPTION
optre=$(sed 's/://g;s/.*/-[&]/' <<<"$OPT_STR")
while getopts "$OPT_STR" opt;
do
    #change here i,o,c to your options
    case $opt in
    i) OPTION[$opt]=$(checkarg "$OPTARG" $opt) || exit 1;;
    o) OPTION[$opt]=$(checkarg "$OPTARG" $opt) || exit 1;;
    c) OPTION[$opt]=1;;
    h) phelp || exit 1;;
    :) required_arg "$OPTARG" || exit 1 ;;
    \?) err "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" || exit 1;;
    esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))
#change here your options...
echo "iarg: ${OPTION[i]:-undefined}"
echo "oarg: ${OPTION[o]:-undefined}"
echo "carg: ${OPTION[c]:-0}"
echo "remainder args: =$@="

for arg in "$@"
do
    do_work "$arg"
done
```

Answer (score -1):

```
OPTIND=1
while getopts "e:n:t:s:h" opt
do
    case $opt in
        e) echo "e OPTARG=${OPTARG} ";;
        n) echo "n OPTARG=${OPTARG} ";;
        t) echo "t OPTARG=${OPTARG} ";;
        s) echo "s OPTARG=${OPTARG} ";;
        h) echo "h OPTARG=${OPTARG} ";;
    esac
done
```

Comment: I am not actually looking for counter examples. I am trying to understand why my example does not work. In my example, I would expect at least the arguments be printed, I understand that why the values are not being printed.

Comment: Do you mean why -e and -s are not being printed? they are printed for me when I use your code example at the top.